# Tooltip Issue with jQuery

Tags: php, javascript

I have this code

```
<?php
if(!empty($auction['Auc']['beginner'])){
?>   

<a href="#" id="trigger_beginner"><?= $html->image('badge/beginner_icon.png', array('width'=>"30", 'height'=>"30", 'border'=>"0", 'alt'=>"Beginner auction", 'title'=>"Beginner auc"))?></a>
<div class="tooltip">
    <label>Beginner</label>
    <label>For an explanation <a href="/pages/auct#beginner">please click here</a></label>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#trigger_beginner").tooltip();
});
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Issue is when I have two auctions with same auction type for e.g like beginner in this case, then tooltip is only working for one auction. I want it to display tooltip on all similar auctions..

Comment: `id` elements must be unique. Use different id's for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to use this:

```
<?php if(!empty($auction['Auc']['beginner'])){?>   
   <a href="#" class="trigger_beginner"><?= $html->image('badge/beginner_icon.png', array('width'=>"30", 'height'=>"30", 'border'=>"0", 'alt'=>"Beginner auction", 'title'=>"Beginner auc"))?></a>
   <div class="tooltip">
       <label>Beginner </label>
       <label>For an explanation <a href="/pages/auct#beginner">please click here</a></label>
   </div>
   <script>
       $(function() {
            $(".trigger_beginner").tooltip();
       });
   </script>
<?php } ?>
```

ID has to be unique so you need to use different IDs or a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

ID of elements should be unique. No two elements should have same ID. You should use `CSS` class as your jquery selector

```
$(function() {
    $(".yourCssClassName").tooltip();
});
```

Assuming all your auction items has the class `yourCssClassName`